# Protocol Buffer how to define file in request message

Tags: file-upload, protocol-buffers, proto

How to i define a property in the request message that is a file? I need a file to be sent with the request to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've at least two options:

1. As `bytes`
2. By reference

In #1, be aware that there's a limit of 2^32 bytes per message and so you'd need to consider batching larger files across multiple messages and potentially streaming these to the server.

In #2, the file is persisted somewhere (e.g. URL) that's accessible to the server. This avoids (un)marshaling the file into bytes for transfer and potentially avoids unnecessary file accesses until the server process needs the content.